# Laravel 5 directory structure on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and started learning v5 few months back. I have created a sample application and want to deploy it over production (Shared hosting).

The easiest way for me is to put all content including app, vendor, config, tests etc folders directly to public_html but I don't want to do this. I want to keep laravel specific things outside the public_html and put only content from public folder to this directory.

What are the options available to do this?

Also, can I share same laravel installation for multiple applications?

Comment: Do you want to share same larvel installation (`vendor` directory) to avoid uploading it multiple times or is there another reason?

Comment: Yes, to avoid multiple uploading of the same content.

Answer (score 1):

on `public/index.php` add after

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

this:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Now You can change `public` directory to `public_html`

Comment: With this all the folders will reside outside public_html but is it possible to have the laravel installation in /laravel and the use public_html folder for public.

Comment: Further change paths on `index.php` to real path eg.

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code outside of the `public_html` and create a symbolic link from `public_html` to the `public` directory in your laravel directory.

Comment: On some shared hosting instances symbolic linking `public_html -> public` will work.  If this doesn't work, depending on how apache has been compiled - you may need to set the group to **nobody** e.g. `user:nobody`, so check this before you remove the public_html directory and symlink to public.